# How to turn basic information into and object to store for later use

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I created a .txt file named Test.txt using the code below and it worked. Now i want java to read the information back to me and when I do i receive the error INBETWEEN THE TWO PARAGRAPHS OF CODE. I simply want to write to a file, save it, and be able to read it so I can create a small database.
Thanks!

```
package textFile;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class createFile {

private Formatter x;

public void openfile(){
    try{
        x = new Formatter("Test.txt");

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("you have and error");
    }
}


public void addRecords(){
    x.format("%s%s%s", "Coty", "xcallidus", "Password");
}
public void closefile(){
    x.close();
}
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at readToMe.read.readFile(read.java:21)
at readToMe.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

```
package readToMe;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class read {


    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file");
        }
    }
        public void readFile(){
            while(x.hasNext()){
                String a = x.next();
                String b = x.next();
                String c = x.next();

                System.out.printf("%s %s %s", a,b,c);
            }
        }
        public void closeFile(){
            x.close();


    }
}
```

Comment: which is the 907th line?

Comment: @Typo: No that's the 907th line of the Scanner.java class and is not of interest to us. We want to know which line *this* one is: `read.java:21`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels right, I don't know why I assumed that Scanner was a customized class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in

```
public void addRecords(){
    x.format("%s%s%s", "Coty", "xcallidus", "Password");
//This creates CotyxcallidusPassword - Without spaces
}
```

You are adding three strings without spaces and are trying to read them with spaces. It should be

```
public void addRecords(){
    x.format("%s %s %s", "Coty", "xcallidus", "Password");
}
```